# Composer missing after upgrading to OS X 10.11 El Captian

Tags: php, composer-php

So simply put. I did an in-place update from 10.10.5 to 10.11.1 recently and just discovered that my composer package manager is no longer working.

I've tried a number of solutions and have it installed into the correct directory, but my alias 'composer' which was set globally is now not able to find the composer file.

Following the steps as always

First, Download

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Then move

```
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/
```

Then update bash_profile

```
vim ~/.bash_profile
```

Finally add alias

```
alias composer="php /usr/local/bin/composer.phar"
```

And my end result, when calling composer is this

```
Could not open input file: /usr/local/bin/composer/
```

Any ideas why this might happen?

Comment: FWIW all of my aliases remained in `.bash_profile` for me when I upgraded to OSX 10.11. Side note, is `usr/local/bin/` not stored in `$PATH`? You could use composer without using an alias that way.

Comment: Nope, removing the alias did not work

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer by talking to someone on reddit.

///

First off, try going to the composer file in /usr/local/bin and double-click it. It should open up in a new Terminal window. This should at least confirm that the file can be executed.

Second, you shouldn't need to have an alias to use composer. You merely point your path to it like this:

```
export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

If you have any other path variables you'll just attach a colon to the end of it like so:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/php5/bin:~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

Hope this helps.